# MISRA compatible alternatives to sprintf?

Tags: c, stdio, misra

I know the reason why `sprintf` and similar functions such as `snprintf` are banned by MISRA.

However, what's the alternative way to do something like

```
sprintf(buf, "The values are a: %d, b: %d", a, b)?
```

`itoa` seems a candidate, but it has to be used together with functions like `strcat`.

Comment: The solution is to code it yourself. If you only need it for decimal integer to string conversion, it should be trivial to code. As a bonus, a home-made version doing only that, will be some 100 times faster and smaller than sprintf.

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* need a `printf()` derivative, and you fully understand the rationale behind the Rule, the easiest way is to Deviate...

Then you need to ensure that the resultant code is OK by either enhanced review, or additional testing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't want a derivate of printf, but an alternative. I know it's bad to use printf and similar functions. But what should I use to replace them?

Comment: In all fairness, fully understanding the rationale is a bit of an undertaking, as MISRA-C just says don't use these functions because they have lots of poorly-defined behavior associated with them. The main reason why `printf` can never be used in a mission-critical application is however the non-existent type safety of variadic functions - they are broken by language design. I don't see how any serious application could deviate from this rule. It will be very hard to justify why _my_ particular use of stdio.h won't be buggy, where millions of programmers have failed to achieve that before me.

Comment: @Lundin I agree with you.

Comment: I did say DEVIATE (the Rule) not DERIVE (the functions)... ie use the standard library, but understand the risks - although as Lundin says, that it tricky!

Comment: Well, I understand the risk and prefer not to break the rule.

Comment: The issue with lack of type safety of variadic functions does not (necessarily) apply in the context of certain uses of printf: There are compilers and static code analysis tools that handle the special case of printf by parsing the format string and checking it against the arguments passed.